# Autoload for PHP App Engine to load sdk classes

Tags: php, google-app-engine, autoload

Is there a existing module or file to manage autoloading of sdk classes when using PHP GAE ?
This would avoid to require a file when using a class of the google sdk.
Thank you for any clue.

Comment: Actually I can do it with composer, I just have to add "use-include-path" : true to composer.json, and it uses composer's autoloader.

Answer (score 1):

No nothing yet - we're investigating if this is something we want to do provide out of the box.